# Issue returning proper value form a function with callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I'm working on a small app in node.js and I have a module where I fetch a user from the database. I'm having trouble returning the fetched user and I am pretty certain it has something to do with the flow of callbacks but I can't pinpoint exactly what I'm not doing right.

```
//first module

exports.userById = (id) => {

db.executeSql(`SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserId = ${id}`, function(
data,
err
) {
if (err) {
  //handle error
} else {
  //return fetched user    
  return data.recordset;
}
});
} 


//the module where I'm trying to fetch the user

const users = require('../controllers/user');
const id = 1;
const user = users.userById(userId); //this is undefined
```

To clarify I am certain the data.recordset contains the data, but I don't know how to properly return that data to another module. Thanks for any direction

Comment: it's asynchronous.. you can't just return it.. you'll have to move the module call into the callback function itself

Comment: can you demonstrate how I do that please?

Comment: replace `return data.recordset;` with the last three lines of your script. i can;t demonstrate since the question was marked as a dupe. you could starrt by reading that page to understand the problem.

Comment: but that would just lead to a circular reference? I did suspect my issue had something to do with async flow... I'll read up on the link thanks